# Cannot access app in Docker container from outside

Tags: docker, sbt, port, akka-http

```
docker pull kovacshuni/riptube:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
docker run -it -P --name="riptube" kovacshuni/riptube:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
bin/riptube &
curl -X POST -d "Hi there" localhost:8082/notify
INFO 15:55:06 c.h.r.NotificationReceiver$ - Hi there
```

So this worked. But from outside, from the docker daemon's host, it doesn't. Despite the EXPOSE command and the -P parameter.

```
docker port riptube 8082
0.0.0.0:32785
curl -X POST -d "Hi there" localhost:32785/notify
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Why? :( :(

Source code [here](https://github.com/kovacshuni/riptube/tree/question). Dockerfile as well, but pasting right below:

```
 FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8

 RUN apk add --update bash py-pip ca-certificates curl
 RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
 RUN pip install youtube-dl

 WORKDIR /opt/riptube
 ADD target/pack/ /opt/riptube
 EXPOSE 8082
 ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
 CMD
```

Comment: You seem to bind your server to port 8080 in https://github.com/kovacshuni/riptube/blob/question/src/main/scala/com/hunorkovacs/riptube/RipTube.scala. Do you make the association between the exposed port 8082 and the bound port 8080 somewhere?

Comment: My main app is RipTube, but that requires complicated setup. For this question my main is in NotificationReceiver, where i bind to 8082. So that's not it. Also the comparison: from inside the docker container the curl is working to 8082, from outside it doesnt.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem:

replace this:

```
private val httpBindingF = Http().bindAndHandle(ripController.route, "localhost", 8080)
```

with this:

```
private val httpBindingF = Http().bindAndHandle(ripController.route, "0.0.0.0", 8080)
```

Surprisingly, it worked for me!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i'll try that out.

Comment: This is correct answer. `localhost` is hardcoded to `127.0.0.1` in most systems.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not on a Linux machine, I guess you have to forward your port in the vm:

```
$ VBoxManage controlvm "name-of-your-vm" natpf1 "tcp-port8082,tcp,,8082,,8082"
```

Comment: I know, but i tried this on a linux machine as well. Also on a Mac, where i first SSHed to the docker deamon VM and even from there i couldn't access the app.